# SQL select highest column value with select from multiple tables

Tags: sql, greatest-n-per-group

I'm trying to view only the highest value in the RATE column while combining the FirstName, LastName, VacationHours, SickLeaveHours, and HireDate from the other two tables.

Basically, I want to only see the current RATE of each employee without seeing their previous pay history.

```
SELECT HumanResources.EmployeePayHistory.EmployeeID
,HumanResources.EmployeePayHistory.RateChangeDate
,HumanResources.EmployeePayHistory.Rate
,HumanResources.EmployeePayHistory.PayFrequency
,HumanResources.EmployeePayHistory.ModifiedDate
,HumanResources.vEmployee.FirstName
,HumanResources.vEmployee.LastName
,HumanResources.Employee.VacationHours
,HumanResources.Employee.SickLeaveHours
,HumanResources.Employee.HireDate
FROM [AdventureWorks].[HumanResources].[EmployeePayHistory],
[AdventureWorks].[HumanResources].[vEmployee], 
[AdventureWorks].[HumanResources].[Employee]
WHERE HumanResources.EmployeePayHistory.EmployeeID = HumanResources.vEmployee.EmployeeID 
AND HumanResources.EmployeePayHistory.EmployeeID = HumanResources.Employee.EmployeeID[enter image description here][1]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `row_number()` window function to number each employee's rate change and then just take the last one.

Regardless, it's worth mentioning that using implicit joins (i.e., multiple tables in the `from` clause) is considered as a deprecated syntax, and you should probably use explicit `join` clauses instead:

```
SELECT EmployeeID,
       RateChangeDate,
       Rate,
       PayFrequency,
       ModifiedDate,
       FirstName,
       LastName,
       VacationHours,
       SickLeaveHours,
       HireDate
FROM   (SELECT eph.EmployeeID,
               eph.RateChangeDate,
               eph.Rate,
               eph.PayFrequency,
               eph.ModifiedDate,
               ve.FirstName,
               ve.LastName,
               e.VacationHours,
               e.SickLeaveHours,
               e.HireDate,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY eph.EmployeeID
                                  ORDER BY     eph.RateChangeDate DESC) AS rn
        FROM   AdventureWorks].[HumanResources].[EmployeePayHistory] eph
        JOIN   [AdventureWorks].[HumanResources].[vEmployee] ve ON 
               eph.EmployeeID = ve.EmployeeID
        JOIN   [AdventureWorks].[HumanResources].[Employee] e ON 
               eph.EmployeeID = e.EmployeeID) t
WHERE    rn = 1
```

Comment: Fantastic!!! Thank you so much for the information; this is very helpful. I will try to get with the times on my SQL :-)